# Выполнение кода в определенный момент Java

Tags: java

Подскажите, как выполнить какой-то код, допустим, ровно в 18:00?

Comment: Создать задачу в системном планировщике.

Comment: если Linux, то crontab

Comment: А если windows?

Comment: @BrongsGaming в Windows есть [планировщик заданий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_(Windows))

Comment: Как вариант https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html считать сколько в ms до 18:00 и планировать задачу

Comment: Все эти планировщики задач это, конечно, хорошо, но мне нужно выполнять в определенный момент времени именно Java код, а не программы или скрипты.

Comment: [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), [Quartz-scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: Если вы используете Spring, то там есть shedulers

Comment: За Timer спасибо. То что нужно)))